# Is Async Await in Console apps as useful as GUI and ASP.NET apps?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I am currently learning C# Async/Await feature and can see its usefulness in GUI and web apps but I am still trying to figure out its real usefulness in Console apps. Can you give an example that drives home the point?

Comment: I don't teach async/await using console apps because they don't obviously do anything else while they wait. You can certainly make them do other things, but it means they perhaps become more involved than a contrived example to focus on async. Perhaps look at creating a console app that has a TCP listener that processes incoming requests while it also downloads files from a list of UrLs; you could telnet into the listening socket and control the download process by issuing commands like "pause and "resume" and it will respond near instantly, which it wouldn't if a large file was d/l'ing sync

Comment: I don't quite see the problem. Tasks are one of the easiest ways to implement parallel processing. Nothing says that the things happening in parallel have to be user interactions. Just using `Console.Wirteline` and `Task.Delay` one can demonstrate how things happen parallel/interleaved.

Comment: Console application can be very complex than just a demo hello world application. Thisnk about of TCO/IP servers to deliver remote services, or task to manage file systems and so on... In these cases async/await pattern could be a easy way to implement parallel processes

Comment: ``Async/Await`` is not just about preventing GUI from freezing, it also about using resource (CPU, IO) in the best way.

Answer (score 2):

Async allows running more code until tasks are awaited, so if there is more code that can be run simultaniously (meaning - it is not dependent of the other task), it can start right away.

for example:

```
public async Task<string> GetUserFullNameAsync(string firstName)
{
   return await GetUserFullNameAsyncInner(firstName); // gets user name from db in an async fashion - takes 4 seconds
}

public async Task<DateTime> GetFlightTimeAsync(string filghtName)
{
   return await GetFlightTimeAsyncInner(filghtName); // gets filget time from db in as async fashion - takes 4 seconds
}

public async Task<UserDetails> GetUserDetailsAsync(string userFullName)
{
   return await GetUserDetailsAsyncInner(name); // gets user details by its full name from db in an async fashion - takes 4 seconds
}
```

lets look at this function:

```
public async <UserDetails> GetUserDetails(string firstName)
{
   var userFullName = await GetUserDetailsAsync(firstName);
   return await GetUserDetailsAsync(userFullName);
}
```

notice how `GetUserDetailsAsync` is dependent of getting the full name first, by using `GetUserDetailsAsync`.
So if you need to get the UserDetails object, you are dependent of waitig for the `GetUserDetailsAsync` to finish. that may take some time - especailly for heavier actions like video processing and such.
In this example - 4 seconds for the first function + 4 seconds for the seconds = 8 seconds.

now lets look at this second function:

```
public async <FlightDetails> GetUserFlightDetails(string firstName, string flightName)
{
   var userFullNameTask = GetUserDetailsAsync(firstName);
   var flightTimeTask = GetFlightTimeAsync(flightName);

   await Task.WhenAll(userFullNameTask, flightTimeTask);
   return new FlightDetails(await userFullNameTask, await flightTimeTask);
}
```

Notice that `GetFlightTimeAsync` is not dependent on any other function, so if you need say that user full name and flight time, you can do it in a parallel way, so both actions are processed in the same time - hence the total time to wait is faster than getting the full name and then getting the flight time.
4 seconds for the first function + 4 seconds for the second - in a parallel way < 8 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at a different angle on the asynchronous programming than just a way of doing things in parallel. Yes, you can run tasks in parallel but you can find so much code that is using await/async but it is waiting on every asynchronous execution.

What is the point of doing so? There is no parallel execution there...

It is everything about making better use of available system resources, especially threads.

Once the execution reaches an asynchronous code the thread can be released and the threads are limited system resources. By releasing the thread when it’s idling for an IO-bound work to complete, it can be used to serve another request. It also protects against usage bursts since the scheduler doesn’t suddenly find itself starved of threads to serve new requests.
Choosing an async operation instead of a synchronous one doesn't speed up the operation. It will take the same amount of time (or even more). It just enables that thread to continue executing some other CPU bound work instead of wasting resources.

If you have any I/O-bound needs (such as requesting data from a network, accessing a database, or reading and writing to a file system), you'll want to utilize asynchronous programming. No matter if the application is a console one or not.

**Bonus**: If you are wondering: "Ok, my application released the thread but there must be some other thread that is really doing the wait!" have a look at this article from [Stephen Cleary](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html)

Comment: Thanks. So to summarise, regardless of the type of application being used (Console/Web/GUI), the Async/Await feature provides the capability to utilise the idle resources of the system. In GUI this translates into non-freezing experience for the user where as for console and web apps, more gets done using idling/available resources of the system and that however does not necessarily translate into faster execution from an end user's standpoint though at times it might give an illusion of it?

Comment: Async/Await feature provides the capability to better utilise system resources - the threads. This translates that if the application needs many threads for executing a specific job then you will not end up in a thread starvation situation which means that some work should just wait until a thread is free to start it.